# Accessing the text in an element that triggered the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list and I want to change the text on a button when a list item is clicked to the text in the list item. So far, I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.List-item').on("click",function(){
            $('#selectedOption').text("hi");
        }); 
    });
```

This will change the button text to `hi` when any list item is clicked. How can I get the button to display the list item text? Do I need to pass the list item into the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.List-item').on("click",function(){
        $('#selectedOption').text($(this).text());
    }); 
});
```

Because this will refer to what you click.
Also, you can use

```
event.target.innerText
```

to get the clicked li text without jQuery

Answer (score 1):

.text will give you the text

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.List-item').on("click",function(){
        alert( $('option:selected', this).text());
        var txt =  $('option:selected', this).text();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This gives the text in the button, I want to get the text from the list item that was clicked. Any thoughts?

Comment: You proabably need $('option:selected', this).text()

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.List-item').on("click",function(){
            $('#selectedOption').text($(this).text());
        }); 
    });
```

`this` refers to the object on which `onclick` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.List-item').on("click",function(){
            $('#selectedOption').text($(this).text());
        }); 
 });
```