# How to change button text to innerHTML of clicked list item

Tags: javascript, click, innerhtml

I've been searching but all i find are JQuery answers, i'm looking for a vanilla JS solution.

When a list-item gets clicked, i want the button text to change into the `innerHTML` of that clicked `li`.

I'm getting close, but somehow the `current` variable only returns the `innerHTML` of the last list-item.

**So what do I need to change to get the `innerHTML` of the clicked `li` as button text?**

[JS-Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/luuuuuuuuk/96e99Lhc/8/)

```js
var clickHandler = function() {

  document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = current.innerHTML;

};

var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var filterItem = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('LI')

for (var i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
  var current = filterItem[i];
  current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dropbtn">Menu</a>
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>ALL</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*I cut out the css of this dropdown to keep things clear.*

Comment: event.target.innerHTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the text in an element that triggered the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680296/accessing-the-text-in-an-element-that-triggered-the-event)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments change

```
document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = current.innerHTML;
```

To

```
document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
```

```js
var clickHandler = function() {

  document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;

};

var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var filterItem = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('LI')

for (var i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
  var current = filterItem[i];
  current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dropbtn">Menu</a>
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li>ALL</li>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are you listening to an click event, You can use that event to identify on where that event was fired.

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {

  document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML 

};

var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var filterItem = dropdown.getElementsByTagName('li')
console.log(filterItem)

for (var i = 0; i < filterItem.length; i++) {
  var current = filterItem[i];
  current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);

}
```